# jQuery Sortable PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery sortable to manipulate image order and write to a DB. That functionality works well.

**PHP**

```
 echo "<div class='revisionNum'>";
            echo "<ul id='sortable_" . $count ."'>";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $sortImageName = $row['OrgImageName']; 
                $sortPath = "../data/gallery/" . $galleryID . "/images/album/" . $sortImageName;
                echo "<li class='sortPhotos' id='item_{$row['id']}' >";
                echo '<img class="sortImage" src="'. $sortPath .'"/>';
                echo "<p>" . $sortImageName . "</p>";
                echo "</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "</div>";
```

**jQuery**

```
//make sortable
    $(".revisionNum").each(
        function(e) {
        num = e + 1;
        $("#sortable_" + num).sortable(
            {stop:function(i) {
                serial = $("#sortable_"  + num).sortable("serialize");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "../albumUploader/queries/sort.php",
                    data: serial
                });
            },
            opacity:1.0,
            //cursor: move
        });    
    });
```

**MYSQL**

```
foreach($_GET['item'] as $key=>$value) {

    mysql_query("   UPDATE galleryimage
                    SET sort = '{$key}'
                    WHERE id = '{$value}'  
                ");
```

}
The issue is when I have multiple `<div class=''revisionNum>` i am only grabbing the  `serial = $("#sortable_"  + num)` of the last UL if the [.revisionNum], not the actual UL that I am sorting. Thanks for the help on this. Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but I think you are looking for the following:

The variable `num` will change every loop you make in the each-loop. But at the end it will have the value of the last loop. Because `num` seems to be a global variable you can't call it in the stop function. Then it will just use the last value it had. The value of the last loop. (Explains your problem)

To solve this I recommend to change your code to:

```
$(".revisionNum").each(
    function(e) {
    $(this).children("ul").sortable(
        {stop:function(i) {
            num = $(this).children("ul").attr("id").replace("sortable_", "");
            serial = $(this).children("ul").sortable("serialize");
            ...
```

`$(this)` refers to the `$(".revisionNum")` you are looping through and it will be remembered, also in the stop function.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I need the num value as it is the unique identifier that sortable uses. Without that I lose my DB write. I'll add the sql so you see what I am doing with the sort. Should have done that sooner

Comment: I've added a new line: `num = $(this).children("ul").attr("id").replace("sortable_", "");` where `num` is retrieved by the id of the `ul`. Does that solve it?